# Current page layout handle Magento2

Tags: layout, event-observer, magento2-dev-beta

In Magento 1 I could get the current page layout handle like this

```
$handle = Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getAction()->getFullActionName();
```

This would return for example for a product page `catalog_product_view` or `cms_index_index` for homepage.

How can I do the same thing in Magento 2?

I need to get a page handle from within an observer. What should I inject in the constructor in order to be able to access it?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I believe you will need to inject

`\Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http` into the `constructor` and then do:

```
$handle = $this->_request->getFullActionName();
```

Tested this in `Magento\Catalog\Model\Observer` - `addCatalogToTopmenuItems()` as below and it did the trick:

```
public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request
) {
    ...
    $this->_request = $request;
}

public function addCatalogToTopmenuItems(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
{
    $handle = $this->_request->getFullActionName();
    ....
}
```

This is one of the first times i'm playing with Magento2 may be completely the wrong way to do this!

Comment: Thanks. Works nicely. I found that I can also inject an instance of `\Magento\Framework\View\Context` and call $context->getFullActionName(), but I guess your method is cleaner. `\Magento\Framework\View\Context` has a lot of other objects injected and I may not need them.

Answer (score 3):

You can have access in any `$block` by calling `$block->getLayout()->getUpdate()->getHandles()`.

If you prefer, you can create a new module and inject this block in the end of content. For example:

```php
#app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/template/handle.phtml
<?php
use Vendor\Module\Block\Handles;

/** @var Handles $block */
?>
<p>All Handles</p>
<pre><?php var_dump($block->getLayout()->getUpdate()->getHandles());?></pre>

<p>Full Action Name</p>
<pre><?php echo $block->getRequest()->getFullActionName();?></pre>
```

```xml
<!-- app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/layout/default.xml -->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
                <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="handler_debugger"  template="Vendor_Module::handle.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

This would also print the layout handles at the end of any frontend page.

Comment: This will give you all the layout handles applied on the current page. The questionwas about that specific handle determined by the page's module controller and action

Comment: You're right @Marius. I just edited my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You have to just add below line for Template view file and Block file to get current action name of page.

This is nice working with any template file and block file,

```
echo $this->getRequest()->getFullActionName();
```

Output will gives current action name of page.

For product page, **`catalog_product_view`** , for category page **`catalog_category_view`**